# Value of Generic Type when not Explicitly Passed?

Tags: c#, generics

In reviewing some code on github, I have come across this pattern:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public T SomeGenericMethod<TValue>(Expression<Func<T, TValue>> myExpr){
    // ...
}
```

This is the only relevant part of the code. The `TValue` never actually used in the method body, it is only present for use in the `Func<,>` type.

It's use then looks like this:

```
myObj.SomeGenericMethod(x => x.SomeProperty)
```

Note that no generic is passed on the call to `SomeGenericMethod`. I would have expected the compiler to require something like:

```
myObj.SomeGenericMethod<SomeTValue>(x => x.SomeProperty)
```

But it doesn't.

So my question is, what is `TValue` when nothing is explicitly passed as the type to the generic method invocation?

Comment: You're only looking at the perspective from SomeProperty.  You're forgetting about your lambda expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it is `typeof(SomeProperty)`. The C# compiler will auto-discover it. From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx

> You can also omit the type argument and the compiler will infer it.
>
> **The compiler can infer the type parameters based on the method arguments you pass in**; it cannot infer the type parameters only from a constraint or return value. Therefore type inference does not work with methods that have no parameters. Type inference occurs at compile time before the compiler tries to resolve overloaded method signatures. The compiler applies type inference logic to all generic methods that share the same name. In the overload resolution step, the compiler includes only those generic methods on which type inference succeeded.

Note that you can think that that usage is strange, but when you use LINQ, you do it normally. With Line you write:

```
var coll = new[] { new { Foo = 1, Bar = 2 } };
var enu = coll.Select(x => x.Foo).ToList();
```

You don't explicitly say anywhere the type of `Foo` in the `Select`. The compiler deducts it is an `int`.

The signature of the `Select` is:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
```

So the type of `Foo` is the `TResult`

Without this type inference, the anonymous objects would be nearly useless, because you couldn't:

```
class MyClass 
{ 
    public int Foo { get; set; } 
    public int Bar { get; set; } 
}

var coll = new[] { new MyClass { Foo = 1, Bar = 2 } };
var enu = coll.Select<MyClass, ???>(x => new { Bar = x.Foo }).ToList();
```

What would you put in the `???`? By definition of anonymous objects, you can't explicitly name them :-)

Comment: Note that using the `new[] { ... }` syntax is also a shortcut quite similar to generic inferencing

Answer (score 1):

You can get away with not explicitly passing generics when the compiler can perform *generic inferencing*, wherein it will use the type of the arguments passed to determine the generic version to call upon. Note that inference happens at compile time, and thus can have some strange side effects with polymorphism.

In order to support the `T` value, this method would need to be within a `class` which has that `T` as a parameter. Because the class itself is compiled once per argument, any constituent members (including Subclasses!) can use that generic parameter, and this includes using it for the parameter of an argument, or the generic parameter of a further generic call.